# Making link go to servlet to redirect to another page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

SO first off let me begin by saying that my servlet loads the option lists in a form i have just fine.  The problem is when i start from the index.jsp like i want, the lists dont load.  So basically, i want to click a link on the index.jsp to take me to the servlet to then redirect me to the correct page based on the link clicked.  Maybe I have been looking at this too long and just need fresh eyes but I cant get why it wont work.

I have included my Index.jsp and servlet

### Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>



    <form method="get" action="customerServlet">


        <a href="customerServlet?addCustomer">Add Customer</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="customerServlet?addPet">Add Pet</a>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

### Servlet

```
package edu.witc.Assignment03.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Phone;
import edu.witc.Assignment03.model.States;


@WebServlet(description = "servlet to get act as controller between form and models", urlPatterns = { "/customerServlet","/addCustomer","/addPet" })
public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomerServlet() {
        super();
    }


    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        Phone phone = new Phone();
        States state = new States();


        Collection<Phone> phones = phone.getPhoneCollection();
        Collection<States> states = state.getStateCollection();

            session.setAttribute("phones", phones);
            session.setAttribute("states", states);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/customerManagement.jsp").forward(request, response);
        //}

    }







    private List<edu.witc.Assignment03.model.Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();



 private void addCustomer(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
           throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/customerManagement.jsp";
    processRequest(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }

 private void addPet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request)//redirect to index
         throws IOException, ServletException {
    String url = "/pets.jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
  }




    private Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            if (customer.getCustomerId() == customerId) {
                return customer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    private void sendEditCustomerForm(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String url = "/customerManagement.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("customers", customers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request,response);
    }



    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         String uri = request.getRequestURI();
         if (uri.endsWith("/addCustomer")) {
             addCustomer(response, request);
         } else if (uri.endsWith("/addPet")) {
             addPet(response, request);
         }

    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         processRequest(request, response);

        // update customer
        int customerId = 0;
        try {
            customerId = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        Customer customer = getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer != null) {
            customer.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            customer.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
            customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));
            customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
            customer.setCity(request.getParameter("city"));

            customer.setZip(request.getParameter("zip"));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use one parameter and check the value than to manually parse the URL:

```
<a href="customerServlet?action=addCustomer">Add Customer</a>
<br/><a href="customerServlet?action=addPet">Add Pet</a>
```

In your servlet:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
if("addCustomer".equals(action)) { ... }
else if("addPet".equals(action)) { ... }
```

Comment: should i put this in the doPost?

Comment: No. Links always use GET.  I think you've confused yourself by putting the links inside a form.  They are not form submissions even though inside the form.

Comment: Looking at your code again, I suspect that it is never going to do what you think its doing.  You've overcomplicated. MVC does not mean that all form submissions and links should go to the same servlet.  It means they should all go to a servlet before being forwarded to a JSP.  But they should NOT all go to one servlet.  You should make distinct servlets and you'll make less mistakes.

Comment: Its weird ....It works for the addPet but when I click the addCustomer link it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Yeah I do that but I am just begginning jsp and servlets.  It just is frustrating when you are so close and it doesnt want to work

Comment: Because you call `processRequest` and try to forward in there, but also try to forward when returning from there.

Comment: Ok that opens up a new problem now though.  The process request loads all of the things to the option list.  I cant have it in the doGet now because there is an error thrown.  I want to start at the index.jsp click add customer and it go to that form and the lists load.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "forms", this could be the solution to send params to servlet.

```
 <form action="ServletName" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="paramName">
     <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
```

In Servlet:

```
String costumerName = request.getParameter("paramName");
```

If you just use a link like href, you should send the param like:

```
<a href="ServletName?ID=12345">
```

In servlet, same.

```
String costumerName = request.getParameter("ID");
```